# How is defined span(x,A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I was reading (text in French) how an exercise is solved, but there was introduced a concept that I've never seen before. **Vect**$(y,\overline{M})$

Searching I found that **Vect**$(y,\overline{M})$ = **span**$(y,\overline{M})$, but I don't understand how is it defined.

In order to understand what is $\overline{M}$.
Let $E$ be a normed space, and $M$ is a subspace of $E$, then $\overline{M}$ is the closure of $M$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is $\overline M$ supposed to be?

Comment: Oh!, I forgot to specify that, Let $E$ be a normed space, and $M$ is a subspace of M, then $\overline{M}$ is the closure of $M$

Comment: You should add this in to your question via editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span of $y$ and $\overline M$ is just the subspace generated by $y$ and $\overline M$, i.e. the set
$$\{\lambda y+m\mid \lambda \in K,\; m\in\overline M\} $$
where $K$ denotes the base field. In other  words, it is the sum of subspaces $\; Ky+\overline M$.

Comment: That's what I was searching for. Thanks a lot.